# Recently copied file returns all 0s as byte array

Tags: go

I have a go file server that can receive requests of files up 10GB in size. To keep memory usage low I read the multipart form data into a tmp file. I know behind the scenes FormFile does the same but I still need to transfer it to a regular file for some post upload processing.

```golang
    f, header, err := r.FormFile("file")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("could not get file from request %w", err)
    }

    tmpFile, err := ioutil.TempFile("", "oriio-")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if _, err := io.Copy(tmpFile, f); err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("could not copy request body to file %w", err)
    }
```

After this I need to grab the first 261 bytes of the file to determine its MIME type.

```golang
head := make([]byte, 261)

if _, err := tmpFile.Read(head); err != nil {
  return nil, err
}
```

The issue I'm running into is if I try to read directly from tmpFile the byte array returns 261 0 when I print `fmt.Prinf("%x", head)` aka invalid data. To verify the data is valid I was saving it to a regular file opening it in my system and the file (in this case an image file) was perfectly in tact. So it is not a corrupt file issue. To get around the problem I now close the tmp file and then reopen it again and that seems to fix everything.

```golang
    tmpFile, err := ioutil.TempFile("", "oriio-")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if _, err := io.Copy(tmpFile, f); err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("could not copy request body to file %w", err)
    }

    tmpFile.Close()

    tmpFile, err = os.Open(tmpFile.Name())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    head := make([]byte, 261)

    if _, err := tmpFile.Read(head); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
```

Now when I print out the head byte array the proper content is printed. Why is this? Is there some sort of Sync or Flush I have to do with the original tmp file to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading/writing a file changes the current location in the file. After copy, the `tmpFile` is positioned at the end, so reading from it will read 0 bytes. You have to seek first if you want to read from the beginning of the file:

```
io.Copy(tmpFile, f)
tmpFile.Seek(0,0)
tmpFile.Read(head)
```